# C++ for-loop condition

Tags: c++

I  want to know why this loops runs even when result.bad_matches.size()=0

```
for (int i = 1; i <= result.badmatches.size() - 1; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Also, is there any other way I could stop it from running when `badmatches` size is 0 without using an `if` condition?

Comment: The compiler might warn you here, that you mix signed and unsigned types.

Comment: The normal, zero-based, way to write a `for` loop would have helped you here: `for (int i = 0; i != result.badmatches.size(); ++i) // ...`. If you need a 1-based index, you can always make one inside the loop `int j = i + 1`.

Comment: Another general rule (not necessarily for this case, but in general) for inequalities is to avoid minus, e.g. like `i + 1 <= v.size()` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the type `size()` returns. It is probably a standard container and thus will be an unsigned type and those types wrap around on overflow. That means it the result of subtracting one will be the maximum value of that type.

Either use a comparison that doesn't require you to subtract from the size (`<`, `!=`) or just use iterators or a for-auto loop. Under any circumstance you should at least use the same type for iterating as the nested `size_type` of the container and not `int`.

```
for(auto& x : result.badmatches) {
 // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use  `while(result.badmatches.size())` to NOT execute it.

`result.badmatches.size()-1` this will be converted to -1. If its an unsigned integer, then -1 is interpreted as 0xFFFFFFFF(on a 32 bit machine). This will make the loop run for 2^32 or 2^64 times. To avoid this, use `while()` as before IF you're certain that `result.badmatches.size()` will return 0.

Answer (score 1):

size must be returning an unsigned so 0-1 is getting upgraded to unsigned and so is the left value. 
So for int size of 4 bytes, -1 will be represented as 2^32 -1 in unsigned int.

If you don't want this behavior then just cast it like this : **static_cast <signed int >** (result.badmatches.size());

PS: I've not touched C++ for past 4 years pl. excuse little mistakes.

The right way is:

```
for (int i=0;i< result.badmatches.size() ;++i)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically don't want this loop to enter when the sise of the collection is zero then you could check for `! badmatches.empty()` assuming that badmatches is an STL container. However, if you structure your code slightly differently, you'll probably overcome this issue without having to do that:

```
for (size_t i=0; i < result.badmatches.size(); i++)
{
}
```

I've changed the `int` to `size_t` which is the same type that `size()` returns (an unsigned integer), changed the initial value to 0 and the comparison so that it will exit if `i >= result.badmatches.size()` Generally, I'd say that this is the clearest way of presenting an indexed approach as it matches the natural indexing of collections and if you need 1, 2, 3 ... rather than 0, 1, 2 in your loop, then you can address that within it.

If you're still having problems, two questions:

1. Is there anything in your loop that might alter the value of `result.badmatches.size()`?
2. Is your code multithreaded with a possibility that `result.badmatches.size()` could change by actions on another thread?

Comment: `size_type` is usually but not necessarily the same as the `size_type` of a container. It works most of the time but will fail you in obscure situations.

Comment: You man `size_t` is usually the same as `size_type`? Yes, that's a fair point. So strictly it should be `size_type` for the container. I must admit I've never found a case where they're not the same.

Answer (score 0):

After understanding the problem explained by @Prototype Stark @Aga , i came to a more simpler solution , using which i can keep my initial index to 1 .

```
for(int i=1;i+1<=result.badmatches.size();i++)
```

Thanks for all the help , it's much clearer now .